# Singularity of complete intersection irreducible curves in $\mathbb{P}^3$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a very general smooth hypersurface of degree $d (\ge 5)$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$ and $Y$ be another smooth hypersurface of degree $d^{\prime}$, where $3 \le d^{\prime} \le (d-1)$ such that $X \cap Y$ is irreducible. Is there any effective bound on the number of node on $X \cap Y$? Of course, there is a bound given by the gennus of a smooth complete intersection curve of degree $dd^{\prime}$. I am looking for more effective bound.

Comment: Just to clarify, is it assumed that $X \cap Y$ has at most nodal singularities?

Comment: Yes. I hope if we allow other singularities then number of singular points will be less.